# check the checkboxes if it is not checked using icheck() in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, icheck

There are many check box.if the checkboxes are uncheck i have to checked.

```
$('.group_select').iCheck('uncheck').trigger(checked);
```

but that is not working.I tried this in jquery.

Comment: @JqueryKing what are you trying to say ur above comment to op

Comment: is this the plugin you're using? http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

if `.group_select` is a parent which contains all the checkboxes then you can do as below

```
$('.group_select').find('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck('check');
```

if `.group_select` is the common `classname` given to your `checkbox` you can just write as below:

```
$('.group_select').iCheck('check');
```